# The OpenCV lib with c++ - in Detail cv::Mat::at causes SIGSEGV on large images

Tags: c++, opencv

I am currently writing an application in c++ using the openCV-lib (version 2.1).
The task was to implement a small database as a students project, using some of the features of this library. My very own implementations of the median-filter and the boxcar-filter use the cv::Mat::at method to access single pixels in a given image with both reading and writing operations.

The curious thing about this is: It works just perfect on smaller images.
but only larger images it allways generates a SIGSEGV, allways on the same coordinates.

Is this a know bug or am i really doing something wrong?

here are the most significants functions i wrote:

```
class point {
public:
    int x,y;
};

class ImageEntry {  
    friend class ImageDB;
private:
    string _key;
    string _filename;
    Mat *_data;
    ImageEntry* _next;
    void show(void);
public:
    void operator<<(ImageFilter* x);
    ~ImageEntry();  
    ImageEntry(string filename, string key);
    Vec3b GetPoint(int x, int y);
    point GetSize(void);
    void SetPoint(int x, int y, Vec3b color);
};


point ImageEntry::GetSize(void) {
    point iRet;
    iRet.x = _data->cols;
    iRet.y = _data->rows;
    return iRet;
}

Vec3b ImageEntry::GetPoint(int x, int y) {
    Vec3b iRet;
    iRet = _data->at<Vec3b>(x,y);
    return iRet;
}

void ImageEntry::SetPoint(int x, int y, Vec3b color) {
    _data->at<Vec3b>(x,y) = color;
}

void MedianFilter::filterImage(ImageEntry* img) {
    Vec3b Points[9];
    Vec3b NewColor;

    unsigned char ActChan[9];
    point range = img->GetSize();
    for (int act_x = 1; act_x < (range.x - 1); act_x++) {
        for (int act_y = 1; act_y < range.y - 1; act_y++) {
            Points[0] = img->GetPoint(act_x-1,act_y-1);
            Points[1] = img->GetPoint(act_x,act_y-1);
            Points[2] = img->GetPoint(act_x+1,act_y-1);
            Points[3] = img->GetPoint(act_x-1,act_y);
            Points[4] = img->GetPoint(act_x,act_y);
            Points[5] = img->GetPoint(act_x+1,act_y);
            Points[6] = img->GetPoint(act_x-1,act_y+1);
            Points[7] = img->GetPoint(act_x,act_y+1);
            Points[8] = img->GetPoint(act_x+1,act_y+1);

            for (int act_color = 0; act_color < 3; act_color++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) ActChan[i] = Points[i][act_color];
                SelSort9(ActChan);
                NewColor[act_color] = ActChan[4];
            }
            img->SetPoint(act_x,act_y,NewColor);
        }
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate any suggestion.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: How large is "large" and what are the coordinates that always produce a SIGSEGV?

Comment: The Image is 850x649 pixels big. the SISGSEV appears on x = 711 and y=8 (in the function SetPoint) - another image is 2244x626 pixels big. with image the error appers with x=1144 and y=1 in "at" called in GetPoint

Comment: You might be missing the copy constructor and assignment operator.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the function `at()`, which you use in the SetPoint() method, in the [documentation of OpenCv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#cv-mat-at), it says:

```
template<typename _Tp> _Tp& Mat::at(int i, int j)
```

Return reference to the specified matrix element.
Parameters:

```
i – The 0-based row index
j – The 0-based column index
```

Furthermore, if you look at your GetSize() method, you set `iRet.y = _data->rows` and then in the method `filterImage()` use a for loop to loop from `act_y = 1 to iRet.y`. The second loop, loops through the rows. At the end of this method you call `SetPoint(act_x, act_y)`, which on its turn calls `at(act_x, act_y)` basically.

Recall that `act_y` was an index of a row, but is now being used as index of a column. I hope this suggestion is all you need to solve your problem.

Comment: Oh gosh.... that did the trick.
Tank you very very very much!
Sometimes you need someone to tell you 2+2 is 4...